# Invoke varargs method

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, variadic-functions

How can I invoke a varargs method using reflection? Like this one:

```
public static void ArgsMethod(__arglist)
{
    ArgIterator ai = new ArgIterator(__arglist);
    while(ai.GetRemainingCount() > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(TypedReference.ToObject(ai.GetNextArg()));
    }
}
```

`typeof(Program).GetMethod("ArgsMethod").Invoke(null,new object[0])` throws *NotSupportedException*.

Comment: I suspect you'll need `TypedReference`.

Comment: Call the GetMethod passing the method name and the array of types of your method parameters. For varargs method, the type is an array of Object.

Comment: @Max 1) `GetMethod(string, Type[])` only checks fixed parameter types, it doesn't create the method based on vararg types. 2) It would rather be an empty Type array, as I don't pass any objects to the method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `RuntimeMethodInfo` simply doesn't support this (it explicitly checks and throws if the calling convention of the method is `VarArgs`), you'll have to write a wrapper that takes a regular `Object[]`, generates IL for calling the method, and invokes that. `ILGenerator` *does* support varargs-methods through `EmitCall`. The MSDN is even helpful enough to have [a sample that demonstrates this exact scenario](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator.emitcall).

Of course, it's not exactly *convenient*, but then nothing about varargs is, really.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure it's what you want, but this work for me;

```
class Program
    {
        public static void ArgsMethod(params object[] args) 
        {
            foreach (var par in args)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("variable has type: " + par.GetType() );

             }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type[] types = new Type[1];
            types[0] = typeof(object[]);
            MethodInfo m = typeof(Program).GetMethod("ArgsMethod", types);
            object[] parameters = new Object[1];
            parameters[0] = args;
            m.Invoke(null, parameters);
        }
    }
```

`params` is not the same thing of `__arglist` but if you develope a method in c# may be better to use params.

See http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/09/28/4473.aspx

Comment: `__arglist` is not `params`.